# What does "arrive from" exactly mean

Tags: meaning

"I have just arrived from France?"

This sentence means "I have just come to France and I am in France now" or "I have come back to the my country from France and I am not in France now?"

My native language is very different from english and it is a little hard to understand for me

Comment: Use that dictionary. What does "arrive" mean? What is its past tense form? What does "from" mean, what kind of a word is "from"? You can figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your journey starts *from* some place and takes you *to* your destination.  If you arrived from France, that's where you started and you ended up somewhere else.  That could be your country or one of the 195 countries that are not France.